# Clean URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my websites user profile page is

```
http://website.com/profile?name=test
```

I'm using get method to **get the variable name** 
I'm trying to make above url to be cleaned like,

```
http://website.com/test
```

My .htaccess contents

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /creatorsink/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there any way to do this with an option to get name too ?

Comment: what is this to do with PHP?

Comment: Yes, there is. There just so happens to be thousands of websites out there with tutorials on how to achieve this simple `mod_rewrite` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite`. For example, your `.htaccess` file should look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here's a brief explanation of the above:

- `RewriteEngine On` turns the engine on (as expected).
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` does not rewrite anything if the request filename exists, and is a file.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` does not rewrite anything if the request filename exists, and is a directory.
- `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]` this is the actual rewrite rule. It takes anything after the domain name (anything other than forward slashes), and rewrites it to `profile.php`, passing it as the `name` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. I'm getting object not found error. Experimenting this in Xampp server. I tried both http://website.com/profile?name=test and http://website.com/test

Comment: Is `profile` a directory, or a PHP file?

Comment: Then you need to use `profile.php`, not `profile?` as you passed in the question. The answer was updated.

Comment: Ben, One issue in this. I'm getting profile page contents if i access other pages like http://website.com/portfolio?id=2113

Comment: Is `portfolio` a valid directory?

Comment: sorry it's profile not portfolio and it's not a directory, it's a page. i'm using mod rewrite rule to remove .php form all pages. Kindly check edited question for my .htaccess contents.

Comment: Any idea where i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Yes, your rules collide. One confuses the other.

Comment: Any suggestion to solve this ?

Comment: Try placing my rule after yours in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: well explained, thanks

Comment: @BenM need your help. `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ folderabc/profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]` works when I search for `http://website.com/testvalue` . But I want the `RewriteRule` against `http://website.com/location/testvalue`. Can you assist me in writing a valid ReWriteRule to accomodate `location`? I tried but cannot make it work